# Using the same font with different sizes in libgdx

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

I am using BitmapFonts, LabelStyles and Labels for my texts.

I want to resize some labels, so I use this:

```
fontType.scale(-.6f);

LabelStyle style = new LabelStyle(fontType, Color.WHITE);

titleLabel = new Label("Points", style);
titleLabel.setColor(Color.RED);
titleLabel.x = 260; 
titleLabel.y = 310;
```

But when I want to resize another label, all the labels containing that font resize (I create a new LabelStyle). So I resize the label instead of the font, but that doesnt solve the problem, because it doesnt resize the label, any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to create separate BitmapFonts and LabelStyle for each Label(or groups of Labels) if you want to scale them independently.

From checking libgdx source code, [Label](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/95d6d9197f269d9d35d6f0d72f9e30d4f121095f/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.java) uses the reference to BitmapFont from LabelStyle and passes it to a [BitmapFontCache](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFontCache.java?source=cc) used internally; no deep copy is made at any point so they are all using the same BitmapFont you created the LabelStyle with.

Comment: I think that will be the best option :/ although it consumes a lot of time creating the bitmapfonts u.u thanks :)

Comment: a shame that label.setScale() is useless. I also think this is the best solution, although it is ugly. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 13):

I am using libgdx 0.9.8 (since this is an old question), and when I created a label as such:

```
lblA = new Label("A", skinA);
```

I can resize the font of just that label with:

```
lblA.setFontScale(3);
```

This doesn't affect other labels I have that were created the same way. I have set some of my labels to font scale (2), and those are OK (not impacted by the (3)). However, I'm finding that styling my label isn't as 'independent'. They need to have their own LabelStyle assigned, otherwise you get the behavior you're stating.

Comment: As of libGDX 1.5.6 (if not earlier), using `setFontScale(float)` impacts labels individually, even if they share the same `LabelStyle`.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Is there something like a global setting to scale everything up? Everything is drawn so small on a phone (more pixel density) but that also means i can get away with drawing the font 2 or even 3 times larger and saving texture space.

Comment: Good question @MennoGouw - I'm afraid I'm not sure :( If it were me I think I'd just create some sort of global function or `LabelStyle`.